# Do the task asynchronously but reply first

Tags: java, asynchronous, servlets, vert.x

This is my first try to do a asynchronous program with java.

My requirement is that whenever I receive a request I have to start a task which may take an hour. Therefore I have immediately reply to the user that “ the task has started” before the task finishes. I amusing apache timcat version 8.5.23.

I assumed that `AsyncContext.start()` will help me but what I found that AsyncContext won’t return the response to the client until it calls the `onComplete(AsyncEvent event)`.

Is there a way I can respond to the user before `onComplete(AsyncEvent event)` happens?

I did see a similar question [How to execute code after response in JavaEE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572481/how-to-execute-code-after-response-in-javaee) .

I heard that https://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs/ may help me but before diving into deep;  I am wondering, is there any other better way or technology to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `AsyncContext.start(Runnable)`, I used `CompletableFuture.runAsync(Runnable)` and it worked as expected.