# Using completable future to do the asynchronous task in a servlet cause java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: asynchronous, servlet-3.0, completable-future

I am facing an issue in my deployment where I am using a **completable future** to do **asynchronous task** in tomcat servlet (version 8.5.23).
I am aware that my following question do not say much about the implementation details  but unfortunately I could  not come up with a simple example to recreate the issue. Please pardon me for that. I hope that some experts in the field can give me high level advice or suggestion which I could further look into it.

It’s a follow up of my previous question [Do the task asynchronously but reply first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217289/do-the-task-asynchronously-but-reply-first).

What I would like to do was  “whenever I receive a request from the client then I have to start a task which may take an hour. Therefore I have immediately reply to the user that ‘the task has started’ before the task finishes.

I initially used `AsyncContext.start()` to do this but what I found that AsyncContext won’t return the response to the client until it calls the `onComplete(AsyncEvent event)`.

Therefore I replaced `AsyncContext.start()` with `CompletableFuture.runAsync(Runnable)`. It initially appeared to me that it’s doing the correct job but later I found out that it’s giving me an issue.

In  my task I was using `com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxyFactory.create(Class api, String urlName)` to create proxy class of backend interface but
after using  the completable future then a runtime crash occurs  `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface MyInterface is not visible from class loader`.

I will be grateful if, somebody can throw some light into the issue

Answer (score 1):

I found out a solution for my issue. It seems to work now but I do not know whether it would it create a new issue. I basically ensured that the async task used the same class loader.

```
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
try {
       Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
       .......
```